# excel, calculate change +/- week by week, green, red with plus and minus

Tags: excel, formula

I need to build a tracker and one of the fields is a +/- which tracks how many new items this week were added or subtracted. I know how to take one cell and subtract the other in excel to track the weekly progress. I can't figure out how to get the + or - in front of it without manually putting it in myself. I need help there. Also, I would like it to be formatted green if positive and red if negative. If zero, black or green should be find. If negative, I am also fine if it is in parentheses. For example, -4 can be (4) in red. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Play around with a custom number format, for example something like `[Green]+#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)`

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks. Instead of going with that green and red, I will just use black. It's easier for me to see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The Plus-Minus

Here `IFS` could be useful, but not all Excel versions have that.

```
=IF(C2>0;"+";IF(C2<0;"-";"No change"))
```

### The conditional formatting

Select the column -> conditional formatting -> apply the color rules for each outcome `(+,-,No Change)`. Pretty straight forward